# Match pandas column values and headers across dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 3 files that I am reading into dataframes (https://pastebin.com/v7BnSH3s)

**map_df:** Maps `data_file` headers to `codes_df` headers

```
Field Name             Code Name
Gender              gender_codes
Race                race_codes
Ethnicity           ethnicity_codes
```

**code_df:** Valid codes

```
gender_codes   race_codes     ethnicity_codes
1                  1               1
2                  2               2
3                  3               3
4                  4               4
NaN               NaN              5
NaN               NaN              6
NaN               NaN              7
```

**data_df:** the actual data that needs to be checked against the codes

```
Name  Gender  Race   Ethnicity
Alex    99     1         7
Cindy   2      4         5
Tom     1      99        1
```

**Problem:**
I need to confirm that each value in every column of `data_df` is a valid code. If not, I need to write the `Name`, the invalid value and the column header label as a new column. So my example `data_df` would yield the following dataframe for the `gender_codes` check:

**result_df:**

```
Name Value  Column
Alex    99  Gender
```

**Background:**

- My actual data file has over 100 columns.
- A code column can map to multiple columns in the `data_df`.
- I am currently not using the `map_df` other than to know which columns map to 
  which codes. However, if I can incorporate this into my script, that would be 
  ideal.

**What I've tried:**
I am currently sending each code column to a list, removing the `nan` string, performing the lookup with `loc` and `isin`, then setting up the `result_df`...

```
# code column to list
gender_codes = codes_df["gender_codes"].tolist()

# remove nan string
gender_codes = [gender_codes 
               for gender_codes in gender_codes
               if  str(gender_codes) != "nan"]

# check each value against code list
result_df = data_df.loc[(~data_df.Gender.isin(gender_codes))]
result_df = result_df.filter(items = ["Name","Gender"])
result_df.rename(columns = {"Gender":"Value"}, inplace = True)
result_df['Column'] = 'Gender'
```

This works but obviously is  extremely primitive and won't scale with my dataset. I'm hoping to find an iterative and pythonic approach to this problem.

**EDIT:**
Modified Dataset with np.nan

https://pastebin.com/v7BnSH3s

Comment: so the columns in `codes_df` should by `gender_code` etc and not `gender_list` etc?

Comment: @anky_91, yup, just fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Boolean indexing

I'd reformat your data into different forms

```
m = dict(map_df.itertuples(index=False))
c = code_df.T.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(set)
ddf = data_df.melt('Name', var_name='Column', value_name='Value')

ddf[[val not in c[col] for val, col in zip(ddf.Value, ddf.Column.map(m))]]

   Name  Column  Value
0  Alex  Gender     99
5   Tom    Race     99
```

---

#### Details

```
m  # Just a dictionary with the same content as `map_df`

{'Gender': 'gender_codes',
 'Race': 'race_codes',
 'Ethnicity': 'ethnicity_codes'}
```

---

```
c  # Series of membership sets

ethnicity_codes    {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0}
gender_codes                      {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
race_codes                        {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
dtype: object
```

---

```
ddf  # Melted dataframe to help match the final output

    Name     Column  Value
0   Alex     Gender     99
1  Cindy     Gender      2
2    Tom     Gender      1
3   Alex       Race      1
4  Cindy       Race      4
5    Tom       Race     99
6   Alex  Ethnicity      7
7  Cindy  Ethnicity      5
8    Tom  Ethnicity      1
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. As an afterthought, it's possible that `data_df` may have nulls. If that's the case, I could add criteria to the list comprehension "`notna()`", correct?

Comment: you could... but if you provided an example, I could probably come up with something cleaner.

Comment: gotcha, just added some NaN values to `data_df` (https://pastebin.com/v7BnSH3s). Thanks!

Comment: The trick is getting the dictionary or series of acceptable sets.  I can add `np.nan` to `ethnicity_codes` with `c = code_df.T.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(set); c.at['ethnicity_codes'] |= {np.nan}`

Comment: Ah gotcha, that makes sense. I was thinking of a much more complicated workaround. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to preprocess your dataframes and define a validation function. Something like below:

**1. Preprocessing**

```
# call melt() to convert columns to rows
mcodes = codes_df.melt(
    value_vars=list(codes_df.columns), 
    var_name='Code Name', 
    value_name='Valid Code').dropna()

mdata = data_df.melt(
    id_vars='Name',
    value_vars=list(data_df.columns[1:]), 
    var_name='Column', 
    value_name='Value')

validation_df = mcodes.merge(map_df, on='Code Name')

Out:

mcodes:
          Code Name Valid Code
0      gender_codes          1
1      gender_codes          2
7        race_codes          1
8        race_codes          2
9        race_codes          3
10       race_codes          4
14  ethnicity_codes          1
15  ethnicity_codes          2
16  ethnicity_codes          3
17  ethnicity_codes          4
18  ethnicity_codes          5
19  ethnicity_codes          6
20  ethnicity_codes          7

mdata:
    Name     Column Value
0   Alex     Gender    99
1  Cindy     Gender     2
2    Tom     Gender     1
3   Alex       Race     1
4  Cindy       Race     4
5    Tom       Race    99
6   Alex  Ethnicity     7
7  Cindy  Ethnicity     5
8    Tom  Ethnicity     1

validation_df:

          Code Name Valid Code Field Name
0      gender_codes          1     Gender
1      gender_codes          2     Gender
2        race_codes          1       Race
3        race_codes          2       Race
4        race_codes          3       Race
5        race_codes          4       Race
6   ethnicity_codes          1  Ethnicity
7   ethnicity_codes          2  Ethnicity
8   ethnicity_codes          3  Ethnicity
9   ethnicity_codes          4  Ethnicity
10  ethnicity_codes          5  Ethnicity
11  ethnicity_codes          6  Ethnicity
12  ethnicity_codes          7  Ethnicity
```

**2. Validation Function**

```
def isValid(row):
    valid_list = validation_df[validation_df['Field Name'] == row.Column]['Valid Code'].tolist()
    return row.Value in valid_list
```

**3. Validation**

```
mdata['isValid'] = mdata.apply(isValid, axis=1)
result = mdata[mdata.isValid == False]

Out:

result:
   Name  Column Value  isValid
0  Alex  Gender    99    False
5   Tom    Race    99    False
```

Comment: This is a good implementation as well. I dropped the `.dropna()` from `mcodes` in order to although NaN values to pass through. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
m, df1 =  dict(map_df.values), data_df.set_index('Name')

df1[df1.apply(lambda x:~x.isin(code_df[m[x.name]]))].stack().reset_index()

Out:
   Name level_1     0
0  Alex  Gender  99.0
1   Tom    Race  99.0
```